# Rails Nested Attributes JSON Formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

I'm trying to override the 'as_json' method to include nested attributes for an object, but I'm having trouble properly nesting the JSON.

Currently, I have this in Rails for my 'as_json' method.

```
// User.rb

def as_json(options = {})
  json = {:id => id, :name => name,
    :settings_attributes => settings.select(:id,:name), 
    :setting_options_attributes => setting_options.select(:id, :amount)}
  json
end
```

However, `setting_options_attributes` should be nested under `settings_attributes` and I can't find the proper syntax do achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `settings` and `settings_options` are already hashes, you should be able to do this:

```
// User.rb
def as_json(options = {})
  {
    id: id, 
    name: name,
    settings_attributes: settings.select(:id,:name).merge({
      setting_options_attributes: setting_options.select(:id, :amount)
    }, 
  }
end
```

If `settings` and `settings_options` are Models, then you probably need to do something like this:

```
// User.rb
def as_json(options = {})
  {
    id: id, 
    name: name,
    settings_attributes: settings.select(:id,:name).map(&:attributes), 
  }
end

// Setting.rb
def attributes
  {
    id: id, 
    name: name,
    setting_options_attributes: setting_options.select(:id,:amount).map(&:attributes), 
  }
end
```

It's a little confusing in that `SettingOption` appears to belong_to `User` (as you reference it directly) yet you want to nest it within `Setting`, which implies that it is a "belongs_to :through" relationship, at which point I think you should make `Setting` responsible for the nesting.

Lastly, if you want to develop complex JSON output, rather than override as_json, you should consider using [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) (which is typically bundled with rails) as it moves your JSON logic out of your model and into the view, which is arguably the more appropriate place to be constructing how you view your data.  JBuilder is much better at designing complex JSON.